# Rotating list items 90 degrees in CSS behaves strangely

Tags: css, transform, rotation

I am attempting to rotate an unordered list in CSS3. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YGXJr/2/

The list items disappear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider the `transform-origin` of the elements, changing it to:

```
-vendor-transform-origin: bottom left;
```

keeps the list items visible, albeit they appear, in Chromium, entirely stacked upon each other to the left. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YGXJr/3/).

Reference:

- [`transform-origin` at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform-origin).

Comment: Is there a way to not have them stack on each other in Chrome?

Comment: Not that I've found as yet, no. But I've got no idea why they're doing that in the first place...

Comment: For anyone interested, I managed to pull this off by applying the transform to the ul rather than the list elements. Tested in Chrome 15, FF 8, Safari 5.1, & Opera 11.52. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YGXJr/7/